# Apply an animation to CSS menu items without access to the HTML

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-animations

I'm creating a Wordpress site where certain sections of the markup are unavailable for me to edit directly because the theme I'm adapting appears to generate them dynamically with JavaScript, which is beyond my knowledge.

With that limitation in place, I'm trying to apply a simple animation which slides forward the text of a sub-menu item being hovered over.

Usually I would just wrap the text of each sub-menu in a span and animate that span on hover, but now I need to find a way to do this without touching the HTML markup.

Here's the relevant CSS for the menu:

```
.primary-menu,
.primary-menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none
}

.primary-menu {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: calc(var(--menuItemsSpacing) / -2);
    margin-right: calc(var(--menuItemsSpacing) / -2)
}

.primary-menu a {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: initial
}

.primary-menu>li {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 400;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.primary-menu>li a {
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0); 
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color;
    transition-property: color, background-color; 
}

.primary-menu>li:hover a,
.primary-menu>li:focus a,
.primary-menu>li:active a {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}

.primary-menu .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(var(--menuItemsSpacing) / -4);
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: var(--dropdownTopOffset);
    min-width: 100%;
    display:block;
    margin-left:6px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: var(--dropdownMenuWidth);
    background: var(--dropDownBackground);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(41, 51, 61, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(41, 51, 61, 0.1)
}

.primary-menu .sub-menu li {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: initial;
    line-height: 1.6;
}

.primary-menu .sub-menu li a {
    padding: 13px 25px;
}

.primary-menu .sub-menu li a:hover {
    color: var(--menuHoverColor);
}

.primary-menu .sub-menu:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--dropdownTopOffset);
    top: calc(var(--dropdownTopOffset) * -1);
    left: 0
}
```

And here's a painstakingly simplified version of the generated HTML markup:

```
<nav class="main-navigation">
  <ul id="primary-menu" class="primary-menu menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/about">About</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/about/history/">History</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/about/people">People</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Services</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/what-we-do">What We Do</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/the-library/">The Library</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/the-library/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item" class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/audio-and-video/">Audio and Video</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/donate/">Donate</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/contact/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I've been grappling with this one for a while but can't for the life of me figure out how this can be accomplished with the current markup, so I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you'd like to make? Video, screenshot, ideal code? I'm trying to determine if you need help with the CSS or targeting the element or both.

Comment: @BryceHowitson My bad Bryce, but it's already been sorted. Thanks for the sentiment anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
.primary-menu .sub-menu li a {
    transition: 300ms padding ease-in-out;
}

.primary-menu .sub-menu li a:hover {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/anf29thg/

Comment: That's ingenious, thank you! I forgot to mention it in my question but I'd tried experimenting with animating TranslateX but that just moved the whole item, and the idea of animating padding didn't even occur to me.

Comment: And yes, the missing brace was just a mistake caused by editing the code for the question, it's definitely there in my codebase. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best :)